# In I2C communication slave is not giving proper acknowledgement

Tags: i2c

I am trying to communicate to slave from master by i2c communication. but during 9th clock cycle slave is trying to pull high to low but it only can pull it to half(3.3v to 1.3v). I changed the pull up from 10k to 33k then 4.7k but not getting improvement in result. I also change the slave IC but no improvement. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: This is a hardware question.  You need to ask at electronics.stackexchange.com, not here.  When you do, include details of what the voltage was with only a 33k pull-up, and also measure your supply voltage/current simultaneously if you can to check if you have a short.

Comment: voltage was 3.3V. There is no short the same circuit is working in same pcb for another slave(same IC).